# How to use mapState function in typescript syntax when using vuex?

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vuex

I'm using typescript syntax in my vuejs project that integrated with vuex.
I want to use mapState method as computed in my .ts file but I got a syntax error.
Currently I am using docs suggested syntax for computed function, I mean:

```
 get counter() {
   return  this.$store.state.count;
 }
```

If you read the Vuex docs you will see that using Vuex in this way instead of using `mapState` is very repetitive. Using `mapState` is very easy and useful in large applications. I want to use `mapState` in my Typescript component and I don't know the right way. I've tried the way below to use the `mapState` function and it didn't work.

```
get mapState({
  counter:count
});

// or

get mapState(['name', 'age', 'job'])
```

I'd be grateful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 31):

You may call mapState within the Component annotation:

```
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

@Component({
  // omit the namespace argument ('myModule') if you are not using namespaced modules
  computed: mapState('myModule', [ 
    'count',
  ]),
})
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  public count!: number; // is assigned via mapState
}
```

You may also use mapState to create new computeds based off of your state:

```
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
import { IMyModuleState } from '@/store/state';

@Component({
  computed: mapState('myModule', {
    // assuming IMyModuleState.items
    countWhereActive: (state: IMyModuleState) => state.items.filter(i => i.active).length,
  }),
})
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  public countWhereActive!: number; // is assigned via mapState
}
```

Comment: But how would you use the component annotation to call, for example, mapState for more than one module? Does it matter that the variable you are defining is called `computed?

Comment: @belvederef just call it multiple times 
```
@Component({
  // omit the namespace argument ('myModule') if you are not using namespaced modules
  computed: {
    ...mapState('myModule', ['count',]),
    ...mapState('anotherModule', ['count',]),
  }
})

Answer (score 12):

Easier using JS [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h2>{{ custom }}</h2>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

@Component({
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      title: 'stuff'
    }),
    // other stuff
  },
})
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {

  title!: string;

  public get custom():string {
    return this.title;
  }
}
</script>
```

Your store:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    stuff: 'some title',
  },
  mutations: {

  },
  actions: {

  },
});
```