# vuex store classbased typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, decorator, store

hey guys im working on a Vue, `Vuex` strongly typed template project using decorators.

Since I'm new to the whole store thing, i cannot get my head around how to properly configure my store to work in my components as i expected.

what i finally want to achieve is calling the actions, ... of my different store modules as follows:

```
this.$store.nameOfMyModule.NameOfAction
this.$store.<nameOfMyModule.NameOfGetter
```

a more concrete exmple for tht project would be

```
this.$store.tickets.tickets
this.$store.tickets.fetchTickets
```

here the link to the [repo](https://github.com/Amnesie91/vue-vuex-ts-template)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use `mapActions` and `mapGetters` :

```
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'

//...

computed: {
   ...mapGetters('tickets', [
        tickets
   ]),
   ...mapGetters('users', [
        users
   ])
},

methods : {
   ...mapActions('tickets', [
        fetchTickets
   ]),
   ...mapActions('users', [
        fetchUsers
   ])
}
//...
```

After that , you can use directly in your component `this.fetchTickets()` and `this.tickets`

Finally you must put `fetchUsers`in action's `users` module , not `fetchTickets`

Comment: so the first string of the mapAction, refers to my store module and the second is a list of all functions i want to get mappted?

Comment: is my store.index correctly figured for that? I saw multiple different ways.
Also, how can i use the spread mapActions operator in a class-style ts format, since i dont have a method or computed object.

Comment: Yes exactly. 
You  can look at those links to know how to make custom component : https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534273/how-to-use-mapstate-function-in-typescript-syntax-when-using-vuex


@Component({
  methods: mapActions('ticket',[ 
      tickets
])
})