# mapState with TypeScript is enforcing me to use watch on my Vue component state properties

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, computed-properties

I am trying to use `mapState` in my `TypeScript`ed written `Vue` component.
As advised here: [How to use mapState function in typescript syntax when using vuex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534273/how-to-use-mapstate-function-in-typescript-syntax-when-using-vuex)
I am doing this in order to achieve it:

```
<template>
  <SomeComponent
    :title="title">
  </SomeComponent>
</template>

<script lang="ts">

import Vue from 'vue'
...

const MyComponentProps = Vue.extend({ })

@Component({
  components: {
    SomeComponent,
    ...
  },
  ...mapGetters(['currentSubscription']),
  ...mapState({
    content: (state: RootState) => state.content,
  })
})
export default class MyComponent extends MyComponentProps {
  content!: ContentModel

get title () {
  this.content.someTitle
}

</script>
```

The issue is I am getting this error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'someTitle')"

When I am getting the state properties directly from the store (not with mapState) I am not receiving any errors:

```
get title () {
  this.$store.state.content.someTitle
}
```

Also when I am using watch I am able to do it:

```
title!: ''
...

@Watch('content')
onPropertyChanged (value: ContentModel) {
  this.title = value.someTitle
}
```

but I find this solution a verbose and less readable one, which in my opinion misses the whole `mapState` idea.
My question is why when directly calling the store I am not getting errors and is there a way for me to use `mapState` with computed properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem, I did not nest the maps in `computed`.

```
@Component({
  components: {
    SomeComponent,
    ...
  },
  computed { // <--- This line solved it
    ...mapGetters(['currentSubscription']),
    ...mapState({
      content: (state: RootState) => state.content,
    })
  }
})
```

This way it is all working fine